# How to get external IP of VM from with VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCP compute instance VM and I would like to get the external IP of the instance from within it?

PS: gcloud is not setup on the instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shell script:

```
PUBLIC_IP=$(curl -s ifconfig.co)
```

From the site:

> Please limit automated requests to 1 request per minute. No guarantee is made for requests that exceed this limit. They may be rate-limited, with a 429 status code, or dropped entirely.

Comment: Works like a charm. Just need it for one time reboot of the VM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For GCP there is also which is more reliable and fast:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor:Google" http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip
```